# Android recyclerview refresh automatic scrolling issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

I have an UI issue when loading data to adapter. List items contains chat-like object, text and images that are loaded via Glide library, and sometimes the RecyclerView position is not right, it scrolls a bit above (using app:reverseLayout="true").

When messages contain no images, it renders out nicely and scrolls to the bottom. But it looks like loading images messes up the scroll position, I've tried with different plugins, but I think that is not the issue.

Did someone experience a similar issue? I am already observing loadstate when it's not loading to scroll to 0 position (Snippet), but it looks like that finishes before layout is finished drawing, and it scrolls down, but after like 300-400ms (sometimes a bit more), it scrolls to the position of the 3rd/4th list item.

Snippet:

```
adapter.loadStateFlow
                // Only emit when REFRESH LoadState for RemoteMediator changes.
                .distinctUntilChangedBy { it.refresh }
                // Only react to cases where REFRESH completes, such as NotLoading.
                .filter { it.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading }
                // Scroll to top is synchronous with UI updates, even if remote load was
                // triggered.
                .collect { binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) }
```

Also, setting a delay didn't help.

I am using RecyclerView and PagingDataAdapter/Paging3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about the recyclerview automatically scroll up on `refresh`, yes, that is a known issue and there is one on the issuetracker as well. Here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186560106 I have solved the issue by adding the following code to scroll to bottom when it is the first set of data being loaded and also `submitData` has been called after the first load.

```
adapter.addOnPagesUpdatedListener {
    if (adapter.itemCount > 0 && isFirstTime) {
        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)
            isFirstTime = false
        }
}
```